# One-loop diagram in scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, antimatter

We see that this loop contain particle with momentum $p+k$ and anti-particle with momentum $k$.

[image]

But I fall into contradiction because the Feynman integral corresponds to this loop (see the book http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/bookwebfinal.pdf  page 57) described boson propagator when we find that there is no anti-particle. What is the interpretation of this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to reinterpret. The diagram you describe (up to factors of $2\pi$ and the coupling constant), has as amplitude the Feynman integral you wrote,

$$I = \int \mathrm d^Dk \, \frac{1}{k^2+m^2}\frac{1}{(p+k)^2+m^2}.$$

This contributes to the process $\phi \to \phi$ where $\phi$ is the incoming scalar particle of momentum $p$. However, recall that the propagator is defined in terms of a two-point correlation function, and thus processes of the form $\phi \to \phi$ can also be interpreted as corrections to the propagator.

---

**Comment Response**

The amplitude is for a *scalar* particle, which means any scalar particle in principle has this as a contribution to its self-energy. An example of a scalar particle is the Higgs boson. The photon is *not* a scalar particle, it is represented by a 1-form, $A_\mu$ and has a different set of self-energy amplitudes.

Comment: Please, can you give me an example, what is the particles that interact by this way?  My specific question is, can I calculate photon self-energy using this integral.

Comment: @Benzian See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my last question is, what is the type of self-energy calculated by this integral, I mean what is the particle that represented by self-energy calculated in this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0206058.pdf . Thank you again